# .NET (C#) Window Minimize Event

Tags: c#, window, minimize

Hey, I'm really stuck with my project here... I need to know when any open window has been minimized / restored and Handle the event in my own App. Any ideas?

Edit:
Musigenesis is right, i do want to know when OTHER applications are minimized/restored

Comment: I assume you want to respond to these events when they occur in other running applications? If so, please edit your question a bit, or you're going to get 30 answers telling you about the Resize event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you would need to use the SetWindowsHookEx Win32 API function (along with a few others).  Basically, you would iterate through all open windows in the OS and hook into their resizing events.

Obligatory comment: are you *sure* you need to do this?  While I think this is theoretically possible, it sounds like a pretty bad idea, and counter to the way applications in Windows are supposed to behave.

Update:  I think "Show Desktop" in Windows works kind of like this, except that it iterates through all the open windows and then uses SendMessage to minimize them if open (total guess on my part).

**Update 2**:  this is a tough one, and I'm very curious to know how this could be done (I'm 100% sure that it *is* possible).  I'll keep an eye on this question, and if no one comes up with an answer in the next day or two, I'll post it again and offer a bounty on it (you could do that, but you need to have some reputation points of your own to offer as a bounty).

Comment: What I'm trying to make, is a sort of virtual dekstop manager (actually an illusion of it) where I keep track of every open window handle and when switching from desktop to desktop I minimize/restore the corresponding windows. With this approach I foresee that down the road I will need to know If a window gets minimized/restored by the user so conflicts don't appear.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Windows Forms, you can handle the [`OnSizeChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onsizechanged%28VS.80%29.aspx), and test the `WindowState`

Answer (score 0):

```
//For cases where you create the window such as:
  protected         Form           gv_AO_frmControlWindow = null;
    gv_AO_frmControlWindow = new Form();
    * * * code to add buttons and such
  // Add handler that is executed when window is minimized/maximized
  gv_AO_frmControlWindow.Resize += new EventHandler(gv_AO_frmControlWindow_Resize);
  gv_AO_frmControlWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;
  // Show window
  gv_AO_frmControlWindow.showDiaglog.


    // ****************************************************************
    private void gv_AO_frmControlWindow_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if ( gv_AO_frmControlWindow.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized ) {
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;
        }
      else {
        notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        }
      return;
      } // END OF gv_AO_frmControlWindow_Resize()
    // ****************************************************************
    private void notifyIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
      gv_AO_frmControlWindow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;  
      return;
      } // END OF notifyIcon_MouseClick()

//Assuming you wanted a system tray icon to maximize window:
    private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon    = new NotifyIcon();

      notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon( "C:\\SysTray.ico");
      notifyIcon.Text = "MyWindow";
      notifyIcon.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(this.notifyIcon_MouseClick);
```

//    Hope this helps.
//                                 Darryl H. Bassett

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?