# What is the event that occurs when a user clicks an icon of application running on taskbar?

Tags: c#

Is there any event occurred when I click on an icon of an application that is **running** and is **minimized** on taskbar? I want to call my method when the icon is clicked.
The method is coded into the app's resource. Please view picture to get more information:

[image: TaskBar Icon]

Comment: Minimized or pinned? There's a slight difference.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384161/net-c-window-minimize-event

Comment: Of course there is an event, you see something happening.  The notification goes to *Explorer*, not your program.  And Explorer will do the normal thing, it restores your window.  Indistinguishable from another way to get a window restored, you get the WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE message.  The taskbar button is not otherwise available to you to mess with beyond the *very* limited interface it provides.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Pawan, LIoyd, Hans Passant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the from Activated event.

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.Activated += Form1_Activated;
}

private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
   {
      //TODO: take required action here
   }
}
```

P.S.:I am assuming that you are looking a solution for winform application.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ramashankar. It works for me

Comment: this works well for me I Use this :

 private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            {
                WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }

so when click on icon taskbar the window get back maximized.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WPF, you can use the [**Window.StateChanged Event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.statechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Definition of this event:

> Occurs when the window's **[WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** property changes.

For WindowsForms, there is no StateChanged event. You'll have to use the [**SizeChanged Event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and check the `WindowState` yourself. Like this:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(this.WindowState)
    {
        case FormWindowState.Minimized: //Your minimized-event code here;
            break;
        case FormWindowState.Maximized: //Your maximized-event code here;
            break;
        default: //state is 'Normal':
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a window is minimized, maximized, or restored, `Window.StateChanged` event is fired. You can trap this event and call your function.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is the same @Ramashankar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it for the same application in which your code is then you handle the `Resize` and `SizeChanged` event of the `Form` control for WinForms application and `StateChanged` event of Window control for WPF application. When user clicks on the taskbar icon of an application which is minimized to task bar, it is restored and the `Resize`(WinForms), `SizeChanged`(WindForms) and `StateChanged`(WPF) events are raised which you can handle and check for the `WindowState` whether it is maximized or normal.

If you want to do it for any other application then I think you will have to use `SetWindowsHookEx` Win32 API function ( as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384161/net-c-window-minimize-event)) so that you will get a collection of open windows in OS and will have to iterate through all such windows to identify and hook into their `Resize` event.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Nitin Joshi